# How to put data in session using flask

Tags: python, flask

this is my register() code

```
        sesOTP = generateOTP()
        session['tempOTP'] = sesOTP
```

and this is `verifyOTP()`

```
mOTP = session['tempOTP']
```

when value is initailizing in `session['tempOTP']`, then it is not going in `verifyOTP()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do two main things. One is to import session from flask library. This can be done using the below snippet of code.

```
from flask import session
```

After that whatever you have done should be able to store the request data in session

```
data = request.form['data']
session['data'] = data
```

Comment: yep that worked, but how can I pass this session value to another function.
Let's say I've saved this in one function and want to pass in another function, so how can I do that?